why am I getting this <{FAIL. Reason: panic: arithmetic underflow or overflow (0x11)]> error
I have a stablecoin project that is based on the MakerDAO DSS system, now I am getting these errors :
Failing tests:
Encountered 2 failing tests in test/fuzz/failOnRevert/StopOnRevertInvariants.t.sol:StopOnRevertInvariants
[FAIL. Reason: panic: arithmetic underflow or overflow (0x11)]
        [Sequence]
                sender=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001106 addr=[test/fuzz/failOnRevert/StopOnRevertHandler.t.sol:StopOnRevertHandler]0x2a9e8fa175F45b235efDdD97d2727741EF4Eee63 calldata=mintAndDepositCollateral(uint256,uint256) args=[3985, 6053]
                sender=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001106 addr=[test/fuzz/failOnRevert/StopOnRevertHandler.t.sol:StopOnRevertHandler]0x2a9e8fa175F45b235efDdD97d2727741EF4Eee63 calldata=redeemCollateral(uint256,uint256) args=[277793815289894506906141823 [2.777e26], 75174257569983732545847661039674497118058820336112449686363 [7.517e58]]
 invariant_gettersCantRevert() (runs: 31, calls: 3917, reverts: 1)
[FAIL. Reason: panic: arithmetic underflow or overflow (0x11)]
        [Sequence]
                sender=0xd2F7fA86FA4a1D53d82d440f31Ae6fbbaF540b13 addr=[test/fuzz/failOnRevert/StopOnRevertHandler.t.sol:StopOnRevertHandler]0x2a9e8fa175F45b235efDdD97d2727741EF4Eee63 calldata=mintAndDepositCollateral(uint256,uint256) args=[4197, 2130]
                sender=0xd2F7fA86FA4a1D53d82d440f31Ae6fbbaF540b13 addr=[test/fuzz/failOnRevert/StopOnRevertHandler.t.sol:StopOnRevertHandler]0x2a9e8fa175F45b235efDdD97d2727741EF4Eee63 calldata=redeemCollateral(uint256,uint256) args=[19619253574758414599525074899301282518119815396501 [1.961e49], 1753173979296313943104446451697151304561265825679564737434168042 [1.753e63]]
 invariant_protocolMustHaveMoreValueThatTotalSupplyDollars() (runs: 29, calls: 3656, reverts: 1)

And I'm not quite sure about a few things:

I'm not sure if this is a simple underflow or overflow error.
I'm not sure if the cause of the error is in the main contract itself or in the StopOnRevertInvariants.t.sol/StopOnRevertHandler.t.sol test and handler files.
I'm not sure that what I think is the problem is actually the real problem.

Here are the files of relevance for context:
main DSCEngine.sol file:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.20;

import {AggregatorV3Interface} from "lib/chainlink-brownie-contracts/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import {OracleLib} from "./libraries/OracleLib.sol";
import {IndexedAssetPriceFeed} from "./libraries/IndexedAssetPriceFeed.sol";
import {ReentrancyGuard} from "lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import {IERC20} from "lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import {SafeERC20} from "../lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
import {DecentralizedStableCoin} from "./DecentralizedStableCoin.sol";

/*
 * @title DSCEngine
 * The system is designed to be as minimal as possible, and have the tokens maintain a 1 token  peg to indexed average price return from the IndexedAssetPriceFeed.sol contract.
 * This is a stablecoin with the properties:
 * - Exogenously Collateralized
 * - Dollar Pegged
 * - Algorithmically Stable
 *
 * @notice This contract is the core of the Decentralized Stablecoin system. It handles all the logic
 * for minting and redeeming DSC, as well as depositing and withdrawing collateral.
 * @notice This contract is based on the MakerDAO DSS system
 */
contract DSCEngine is ReentrancyGuard {
    ///////////////////
    // Errors
    ///////////////////
    error DSCEngine__TokenAddressesAndPriceFeedAddressesAmountsDontMatch();
    error DSCEngine__NeedsMoreThanZero();
    error DSCEngine__TokenNotAllowed(address token);
    error DSCEngine__TransferFailed();
    error DSCEngine__BreaksHealthFactor(uint256 healthFactorValue);
    error DSCEngine__MintFailed();
    error DSCEngine__HealthFactorOk();
    error DSCEngine__HealthFactorNotImproved();

    ///////////////////
    // Types
    ///////////////////
    using OracleLib for AggregatorV3Interface;

    ///////////////////
    // State Variables
    ///////////////////
    DecentralizedStableCoin private immutable i_dsc;
    IndexedAssetPriceFeed private immutable i_indexedAssetPriceFeed;

    uint256 private constant LIQUIDATION_THRESHOLD = 50; // This means you need to be 200% over-collateralized
    uint256 private constant LIQUIDATION_BONUS = 10; // This means you get assets at a 10% discount when liquidating
    uint256 private constant LIQUIDATION_PRECISION = 100;
    uint256 private constant MIN_HEALTH_FACTOR = 1e18;
    uint256 private constant PRECISION = 1e18;
    uint256 private constant ADDITIONAL_FEED_PRECISION = 1e10;
    // uint256 private constant FEED_PRECISION = 1e8; // Never used

    /// @dev Mapping of token address to price feed address
    mapping(address collateralToken => address priceFeed) private s_priceFeeds;
    /// @dev Amount of collateral deposited by user
    mapping(address user => mapping(address collateralToken => uint256 amount)) private s_collateralDeposited;
    /// @dev Amount of DSC minted by user
    mapping(address user => uint256 amount) private s_DSCMinted;
    /// @dev If we know exactly how many tokens we have, we could make this immutable!
    address[] private s_collateralTokens;

    ///////////////////
    // Events
    ///////////////////
    event CollateralDeposited(address indexed user, address indexed token, uint256 indexed amount);
    event CollateralRedeemed(address indexed redeemFrom, address indexed redeemTo, address token, uint256 amount); // if redeemFrom != redeemedTo, then it was liquidated

    ///////////////////
    // Modifiers
    ///////////////////
    modifier moreThanZero(uint256 amount) {
        if (amount == 0) {
            revert DSCEngine__NeedsMoreThanZero();
        }
        _;
    }

    // modifier isAllowedToken(address token) {
    //     if (s_priceFeeds[token] == address(0)) {
    //         revert DSCEngine__TokenNotAllowed(token);
    //     }
    //     _;
    // }  // LOOK INTO THIS -- CAN IT STAY OR CAN IT GO

    ///////////////////
    // Functions
    ///////////////////
    constructor(address[] memory tokenAddresses, address[] memory priceFeedAddresses, address dscAddress, address indexedAssetPriceFeedAddress) {
        if (tokenAddresses.length != priceFeedAddresses.length) {
            revert DSCEngine__TokenAddressesAndPriceFeedAddressesAmountsDontMatch();
        }
        // These feeds will be the USD pairs
        // For example ETH / USD or MKR / USD
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < tokenAddresses.length; i++) {
            s_priceFeeds[tokenAddresses[i]] = priceFeedAddresses[i];
            s_collateralTokens.push(tokenAddresses[i]);
        }
        i_dsc = DecentralizedStableCoin(dscAddress);

        // Check for address(0) assignment
        require(indexedAssetPriceFeedAddress!= address(0), "Invalid indexed asset price feed address");

        i_indexedAssetPriceFeed = IndexedAssetPriceFeed(indexedAssetPriceFeedAddress);
    }

    ///////////////////
    // External Functions
    ///////////////////
    /*
     * @param tokenCollateralAddress: The ERC20 token address of the collateral you're depositing
     * @param amountCollateral: The amount of collateral you're depositing
     * @param amountDscToMint: The amount of DSC you want to mint
     * @notice This function will deposit your collateral and mint DSC in one transaction
     */
    function depositCollateralAndMintDsc(
        address tokenCollateralAddress,
        uint256 amountCollateral,
        uint256 amountDscToMint
    ) external {
        depositCollateral(tokenCollateralAddress, amountCollateral);
        mintDsc(amountDscToMint);
    }

    /*
     * @param tokenCollateralAddress: The ERC20 token address of the collateral you're depositing
     * @param amountCollateral: The amount of collateral you're depositing
     * @param amountDscToBurn: The amount of DSC you want to burn
     * @notice This function will withdraw your collateral and burn DSC in one transaction
     */
    function redeemCollateralForDsc(address tokenCollateralAddress, uint256 amountCollateral, uint256 amountDscToBurn)
        external
        nonReentrant
        moreThanZero(amountCollateral)
    {
        _burnDsc(amountDscToBurn, msg.sender, msg.sender);
        _redeemCollateral(tokenCollateralAddress, amountCollateral, msg.sender, msg.sender);
        revertIfHealthFactorIsBroken(msg.sender);
    }

    /*
     * @param tokenCollateralAddress: The ERC20 token address of the collateral you're redeeming
     * @param amountCollateral: The amount of collateral you're redeeming
     * @notice This function will redeem your collateral.
     * @notice If you have DSC minted, you will not be able to redeem until you burn your DSC
     */
    function redeemCollateral(address tokenCollateralAddress, uint256 amountCollateral)
        external
        nonReentrant
        moreThanZero(amountCollateral)
    {
        _redeemCollateral(tokenCollateralAddress, amountCollateral, msg.sender, msg.sender);
        revertIfHealthFactorIsBroken(msg.sender);
    }

    /*
     * @notice careful! You'll burn your DSC here! Make sure you want to do this...
     * @dev you might want to use this if you're nervous you might get liquidated and want to just burn
     * you DSC but keep your collateral in.
     */
    function burnDsc(uint256 amount) external moreThanZero(amount) {
        _burnDsc(amount, msg.sender, msg.sender);
    }

    /*
     * @param collateral: The ERC20 token address of the collateral you're using to make the protocol solvent again.
     * This is collateral that you're going to take from the user who is insolvent.
     * In return, you have to burn your DSC to pay off their debt, but you don't pay off your own.
     * @param user: The user who is insolvent. They have to have a _healthFactor below MIN_HEALTH_FACTOR
     * @param debtToCover: The amount of DSC you want to burn to cover the user's debt.
     *
     * @notice: You can partially liquidate a user.
     * @notice: You will get a 10% LIQUIDATION_BONUS for taking the users funds.
     * @notice: This function working assumes that the protocol will be roughly 150% overcollateralized in order for this to work.
     * @notice: A known bug would be if the protocol was only 100% collateralized, we wouldn't be able to liquidate anyone.
     * For example, if the price of the collateral plummeted before anyone could be liquidated.
     */
    function liquidate(address collateral, address user, uint256 debtToCover)
        external
        nonReentrant
        moreThanZero(debtToCover)
    {
        uint256 startingUserHealthFactor = _healthFactor(user);
        if (startingUserHealthFactor >= MIN_HEALTH_FACTOR) {
            revert DSCEngine__HealthFactorOk();
        }
        // If covering 100 DSC, we need to $100 of collateral
        uint256 tokenAmountFromDebtCovered = getTokenAmountFromUsd(collateral, debtToCover);
        // And give them a 10% bonus
        // So we are giving the liquidator $110 of WETH for 100 DSC
        // We should implement a feature to liquidate in the event the protocol is insolvent
        // And sweep extra amounts into a treasury
        uint256 bonusCollateral = (tokenAmountFromDebtCovered * LIQUIDATION_BONUS) / LIQUIDATION_PRECISION;
        // Burn DSC equal to debtToCover
        // Figure out how much collateral to recover based on how much burnt
        _redeemCollateral(collateral, tokenAmountFromDebtCovered + bonusCollateral, user, msg.sender);
        _burnDsc(debtToCover, user, msg.sender);

        uint256 endingUserHealthFactor = _healthFactor(user);
        // This conditional should never hit, but just in case
        if (endingUserHealthFactor <= startingUserHealthFactor) {
            revert DSCEngine__HealthFactorNotImproved();
        }
        
        revertIfHealthFactorIsBroken(msg.sender);
    }

    ///////////////////
    // Public Functions
    ///////////////////
    /*
     * @param amountDscToMint: The amount of DSC you want to mint
     * You can only mint DSC if you hav enough collateral
     */
    function mintDsc(uint256 amountDscToMint) public nonReentrant moreThanZero(amountDscToMint) {
        // Retrieve the indexed average price from the IndexedAssetPriceFeed contract
        uint256 indexedPrice = i_indexedAssetPriceFeed.getLatestPrice();
        
        // Calculate the total value of the collateral in indexed units
        uint256 collateralValueInIndexedUnits = (amountDscToMint * indexedPrice) / PRECISION;
        
        // Check if the collateral value meets the minimum requirements for minting
        uint256 totalCollateralValueInIndexedUnits = getAccountCollateralValue(msg.sender);
        require(totalCollateralValueInIndexedUnits >= collateralValueInIndexedUnits, "Insufficient collateral");
        
        
        // Mint the DSC tokens
        bool minted = i_dsc.mint(msg.sender, amountDscToMint);
        if (minted != true) {
            revert DSCEngine__MintFailed();
        }
        
        // Update the amount of DSC minted by the user
        s_DSCMinted[msg.sender] += amountDscToMint;
        
        // Revert if the health factor is broken after minting
        revertIfHealthFactorIsBroken(msg.sender);
    }

    /*
     * @param tokenCollateralAddress: The ERC20 token address of the collateral you're depositing
     * @param amountCollateral: The amount of collateral you're depositing
     */
    function depositCollateral(address tokenCollateralAddress, uint256 amountCollateral)
        public
        nonReentrant
        moreThanZero(amountCollateral)
        // isAllowedToken(tokenCollateralAddress)
    {
        if (s_priceFeeds[tokenCollateralAddress] == address(0)) {
            revert DSCEngine__TokenNotAllowed(tokenCollateralAddress);
        }
        
        s_collateralDeposited[msg.sender][tokenCollateralAddress] += amountCollateral;
        emit CollateralDeposited(msg.sender, tokenCollateralAddress, amountCollateral);
        
        // bool success = IERC20(tokenCollateralAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountCollateral); // Remove this.
        // if (!success) {
            //     revert DSCEngine__TransferFailed();
            // }
            
        // Use SafeERC20's safeTransferFrom method
        SafeERC20.safeTransferFrom(IERC20(tokenCollateralAddress), msg.sender, address(this), amountCollateral);
        }
        
    ///////////////////
    // Private Functions
    ///////////////////
    function _redeemCollateral(address tokenCollateralAddress, uint256 amountCollateral, address from, address to)
        private
        // nonReentrant HERE!!!
    {
        s_collateralDeposited[from][tokenCollateralAddress] -= amountCollateral;
        emit CollateralRedeemed(from, to, tokenCollateralAddress, amountCollateral);
        
        // bool success = IERC20(tokenCollateralAddress).transfer(to, amountCollateral); // remove this
        // if (!success) {
            //     revert DSCEngine__TransferFailed();
            // }
            
        SafeERC20.safeTransfer(IERC20(tokenCollateralAddress), to, amountCollateral);
    }

    function _burnDsc(uint256 amountDscToBurn, address onBehalfOf, address dscFrom) 
    private 
    // nonReentrant HERE!!!
    {

        s_DSCMinted[onBehalfOf] -= amountDscToBurn;

        // bool success = i_dsc.transferFrom(dscFrom, address(this), amountDscToBurn); // remove this.
        // if (!success) {
        //     revert DSCEngine__TransferFailed();
        // }
        
        SafeERC20.safeTransferFrom(i_dsc, dscFrom, address(this), amountDscToBurn);
        
        i_dsc.burn(amountDscToBurn);
    }

    //////////////////////////////
    // Private & Internal View & Pure Functions
    //////////////////////////////

    function _getAccountInformation(address user)
        private
        view
        returns (uint256 totalDscMinted, uint256 collateralValueInUsd)
    {
        totalDscMinted = s_DSCMinted[user];
        collateralValueInUsd = getAccountCollateralValue(user);
    }

    function _healthFactor(address user) private view returns (uint256) {
        (uint256 totalDscMinted, uint256 collateralValueInUsd) = _getAccountInformation(user);
        return _calculateHealthFactor(totalDscMinted, collateralValueInUsd);
    }

    function _getUsdValue(address token, uint256 amount) private view returns (uint256) {
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(s_priceFeeds[token]);
        (, int256 price,,,) = OracleLib.staleCheckLatestRoundDataOnCollateral(priceFeed);
        return ((uint256(price) * ADDITIONAL_FEED_PRECISION) * amount) / PRECISION;
    }

    function _calculateHealthFactor(uint256 totalDscMinted, uint256 collateralValueInUsd)
        internal
        pure
        returns (uint256)
    {
        if (totalDscMinted == 0) return type(uint256).max;
        uint256 collateralAdjustedForThreshold = (collateralValueInUsd * LIQUIDATION_THRESHOLD) / LIQUIDATION_PRECISION;
        return (collateralAdjustedForThreshold * PRECISION) / totalDscMinted;
    }

    function revertIfHealthFactorIsBroken(address user) internal view {
        uint256 userHealthFactor = _healthFactor(user);
        if (userHealthFactor < MIN_HEALTH_FACTOR) {
            revert DSCEngine__BreaksHealthFactor(userHealthFactor);
        }
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // External & Public View & Pure Functions
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function calculateHealthFactor(uint256 totalDscMinted, uint256 collateralValueInUsd)
        external
        pure
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return _calculateHealthFactor(totalDscMinted, collateralValueInUsd);
    }

    function getAccountInformation(address user)
        external
        view
        returns (uint256 totalDscMinted, uint256 collateralValueInUsd)
    {
        return _getAccountInformation(user);
    }

    function getUsdValue(
        address token,
        uint256 amount // in WEI
    ) external view returns (uint256) {
        return _getUsdValue(token, amount);
    }

    function getCollateralBalanceOfUser(address user, address token) external view returns (uint256) {
        return s_collateralDeposited[user][token];
    }

    function getAccountCollateralValue(address user) public view returns (uint256 totalCollateralValueInUsd) {
        for (uint256 index = 0; index < s_collateralTokens.length; index++) {
            address token = s_collateralTokens[index];
            uint256 amount = s_collateralDeposited[user][token];
            totalCollateralValueInUsd += _getUsdValue(token, amount);
        }
        return totalCollateralValueInUsd;
    }

    function getTokenAmountFromUsd(address token, uint256 usdAmountInWei) public view returns (uint256) {
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(s_priceFeeds[token]);
        (, int256 price,,,) = OracleLib.staleCheckLatestRoundDataOnCollateral(priceFeed);
        // $100e18 USD Debt
        // 1 ETH = 2000 USD
        // The returned value from Chainlink will be 2000 * 1e8
        // Most USD pairs have 8 decimals, so we will just pretend they all do
        return ((usdAmountInWei * PRECISION) / (uint256(price) * ADDITIONAL_FEED_PRECISION));
    }

    function getPrecision() external pure returns (uint256) {
        return PRECISION;
    }

    function getAdditionalFeedPrecision() external pure returns (uint256) {
        return ADDITIONAL_FEED_PRECISION;
    }

    function getLiquidationThreshold() external pure returns (uint256) {
        return LIQUIDATION_THRESHOLD;
    }

    function getLiquidationBonus() external pure returns (uint256) {
        return LIQUIDATION_BONUS;
    }

    function getLiquidationPrecision() external pure returns (uint256) {
        return LIQUIDATION_PRECISION;
    }

    function getMinHealthFactor() external pure returns (uint256) {
        return MIN_HEALTH_FACTOR;
    }

    function getCollateralTokens() external view returns (address[] memory) {
        return s_collateralTokens;
    }

    function getDsc() external view returns (address) {
        return address(i_dsc);
    }

    function getCollateralTokenPriceFeed(address token) external view returns (address) {
        return s_priceFeeds[token];
    }

    function getHealthFactor(address user) external view returns (uint256) {
        return _healthFactor(user);
    }
}

StopOnRevertInvariant.t.sol:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

// Invariants:
// protocol must never be insolvent / undercollateralized
// TODO: users cant create stablecoins with a bad health factor
// TODO: a user should only be able to be liquidated if they have a bad health factor

import {Test} from "../../../lib/forge-std/src/Test.sol";
import {StdInvariant} from "../../../lib/forge-std/src/StdInvariant.sol";
import {DSCEngine} from "../../../src/DSCEngine.sol";
import {DecentralizedStableCoin} from "../../../src/DecentralizedStableCoin.sol";
import {HelperConfig} from "../../../script/HelperConfig.s.sol";
import {DeployDSC} from "../../../script/DeployDSC.s.sol";
import {ERC20Mock} from "lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/mocks/token/ERC20Mock.sol";
import {StopOnRevertHandler} from "./StopOnRevertHandler.t.sol";
import {console} from "../../../lib/forge-std/src/console.sol";

contract StopOnRevertInvariants is StdInvariant, Test {
    DSCEngine public dsce;
    DecentralizedStableCoin public dsc;
    HelperConfig public helperConfig;

    address public ethUsdPriceFeed;
    address public btcUsdPriceFeed;
    address public weth;
    address public wbtc;

    uint256 amountCollateral = 10 ether;
    uint256 amountToMint = 100 ether;

    uint256 public constant STARTING_USER_BALANCE = 10 ether;
    address public constant USER = address(1);
    uint256 public constant MIN_HEALTH_FACTOR = 1e18;
    uint256 public constant LIQUIDATION_THRESHOLD = 50;

    // Liquidation
    address public liquidator = makeAddr("liquidator");
    uint256 public collateralToCover = 20 ether;

    StopOnRevertHandler public handler;

    function setUp() external {
        DeployDSC deployer = new DeployDSC();
        (dsc, dsce, helperConfig) = deployer.run();
        (ethUsdPriceFeed, btcUsdPriceFeed, weth, wbtc,) = helperConfig.activeNetworkConfig();
        handler = new StopOnRevertHandler(dsce, dsc);
        targetContract(address(handler));
    }

    function invariant_protocolMustHaveMoreValueThatTotalSupplyDollars() public view {
        uint256 totalSupply = dsc.totalSupply();
        uint256 wethDeposted = ERC20Mock(weth).balanceOf(address(dsce));
        uint256 wbtcDeposited = ERC20Mock(wbtc).balanceOf(address(dsce));

        uint256 wethValue = dsce.getUsdValue(weth, wethDeposted);
        uint256 wbtcValue = dsce.getUsdValue(wbtc, wbtcDeposited);

        console.log("wethValue: %s", wethValue);
        console.log("wbtcValue: %s", wbtcValue);
        console.log("totalSupply: ", totalSupply);

        assert(wethValue + wbtcValue >= totalSupply);
    }

    function invariant_gettersCantRevert() public view {
        dsce.getAdditionalFeedPrecision(); // fails
        dsce.getCollateralTokens();
        dsce.getLiquidationBonus(); // fails
        dsce.getLiquidationBonus(); // fails
        dsce.getLiquidationThreshold(); // fails
        dsce.getMinHealthFactor(); // fails
        dsce.getPrecision(); // fails
        dsce.getDsc(); // fails

        // ------------------------
        // dsce.getTokenAmountFromUsd();
        // dsce.getCollateralTokenPriceFeed();
        // dsce.getCollateralBalanceOfUser();
        // getAccountCollateralValue();
    }
}

StopOnRevertHandler.t.sol:
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import {EnumerableSet} from "lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/utils/structs/EnumerableSet.sol";
import {Test} from "../../../lib/forge-std/src/Test.sol";
import {ERC20Mock} from "lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/mocks/token/ERC20Mock.sol";

import {MockV3Aggregator} from "../../mocks/MockV3Aggregator.sol";
import {DSCEngine} from "../../../src/DSCEngine.sol";
import {IndexedAssetPriceFeed} from "../../../src/libraries/IndexedAssetPriceFeed.sol";
import {DecentralizedStableCoin} from "../../../src/DecentralizedStableCoin.sol";
import {console} from "../../../lib/forge-std/src/console.sol";

contract StopOnRevertHandler is Test {
    using EnumerableSet for EnumerableSet.AddressSet;

    // Deployed contracts to interact with
    DSCEngine public dscEngine;
    DecentralizedStableCoin public dsc;
    MockV3Aggregator public ethUsdPriceFeed;
    MockV3Aggregator public btcUsdPriceFeed;
    ERC20Mock public weth;
    ERC20Mock public wbtc;

    // Ghost Variables
    uint96 public constant MAX_DEPOSIT_SIZE = type(uint96).max;

    constructor(DSCEngine _dscEngine, DecentralizedStableCoin _dsc) {
        dscEngine = _dscEngine;
        dsc = _dsc;

        address[] memory collateralTokens = dscEngine.getCollateralTokens();
        weth = ERC20Mock(collateralTokens[0]);
        wbtc = ERC20Mock(collateralTokens[1]);

        ethUsdPriceFeed = MockV3Aggregator(dscEngine.getCollateralTokenPriceFeed(address(weth)));
        btcUsdPriceFeed = MockV3Aggregator(dscEngine.getCollateralTokenPriceFeed(address(wbtc)));
    }

    // FUNCTOINS TO INTERACT WITH

    // DSCEngine //
    function mintAndDepositCollateral(uint256 collateralSeed, uint256 amountCollateral) public {
        // must be more than 0
        amountCollateral = bound(amountCollateral, 1, MAX_DEPOSIT_SIZE);
        ERC20Mock collateral = _getCollateralFromSeed(collateralSeed);

        vm.startPrank(msg.sender);
        collateral.mint(msg.sender, amountCollateral);
        collateral.approve(address(dscEngine), amountCollateral);
        dscEngine.depositCollateral(address(collateral), amountCollateral);
        vm.stopPrank();
    }

    function redeemCollateral(uint256 collateralSeed, uint256 amountCollateral) public {
        ERC20Mock collateral = _getCollateralFromSeed(collateralSeed);
        uint256 maxCollateral = dscEngine.getCollateralBalanceOfUser(msg.sender, address(collateral));

        amountCollateral = bound(amountCollateral, 0, maxCollateral);
        if (amountCollateral == 0) {
            return;
        }
        dscEngine.redeemCollateral(address(collateral), amountCollateral);
    }

    function burnDsc(uint256 amountDsc) public {
        // Must burn more than 0
        amountDsc = bound(amountDsc, 0, dsc.balanceOf(msg.sender));
        if (amountDsc == 0) {
            return;
        }
        dscEngine.burnDsc(amountDsc);
    }

    function liquidate(uint256 collateralSeed, address userToBeLiquidated, uint256 debtToCover) public {
        uint256 minHealthFactor = dscEngine.getMinHealthFactor();
        uint256 userHealthFactor = dscEngine.getHealthFactor(userToBeLiquidated);
        if (userHealthFactor >= minHealthFactor) {
            return;
        }
        debtToCover = bound(debtToCover, 1, uint256(type(uint96).max));
        ERC20Mock collateral = _getCollateralFromSeed(collateralSeed);
        dscEngine.liquidate(address(collateral), userToBeLiquidated, debtToCover);
    }

    // DecentralizedStableCoin //
    function transferDsc(uint256 amountDsc, address to) public {
        if (to == address(0)) {
            to = address(1);
        }
        amountDsc = bound(amountDsc, 0, dsc.balanceOf(msg.sender));
        vm.prank(msg.sender);
        dsc.transfer(to, amountDsc);
    }

    // Aggregator //
    function updateCollateralPrice(uint96 newPrice, uint256 collateralSeed) public {
        int256 intNewPrice = int256(uint256(newPrice));
        ERC20Mock collateral = _getCollateralFromSeed(collateralSeed);
        MockV3Aggregator priceFeed = MockV3Aggregator(dscEngine.getCollateralTokenPriceFeed(address(collateral)));

        priceFeed.updateAnswer(intNewPrice);
    }

    /// Helper Functions
    function _getCollateralFromSeed(uint256 collateralSeed) private view returns (ERC20Mock) {
        if (collateralSeed % 2 == 0) {
            return weth;
        } else {
            return wbtc;
        }
    }
}

I think the numbers the fuzz tests are passing in which are causing the test to fail is realistically unfeasible, but I also suspect there is something wrong somewhere in the main and test files.
I can't think of more info to provide, I just can't conceptualize the error, please more experienced solidity dev I would much appreciate your help. please ask questions.
I have been trying to solve this for almost 2 weeks now, I feel so dumb lol.

As, dscEngine.redeemCollateral() is not pranked by msg.sender, therefore it's getting called by the address of the StopOnRevertHandler contract itself.
And since, the StopOnRevertHandler hasn't deposited any collateral, so when the redeemCollateral() function is being called using its address, it's basically trying to deduct the collateral amount (i.e., amountCollateral) from the collateral balance of the contract (i.e., 0) , thereby causing the test to revert with the underflow error:
[FAIL. Reason: panic: arithmetic underflow or overflow (0x11)]

So, in order to solve this, you just need to add vm.prank(msg.sender); before calling dscEngine.redeemCollateral() function.
The revised redeemCollateral() function in the StopOnRevertHandler contract would be:
function redeemCollateral(uint256 collateralSeed, uint256 amountCollateral) public {
    ERC20Mock collateral = _getCollateralFromSeed(collateralSeed);
    uint256 maxCollateral = dscEngine.getCollateralBalanceOfUser(msg.sender, address(collateral));

    amountCollateral = bound(amountCollateral, 0, maxCollateral);
    if (amountCollateral == 0) {
        return;
    }
    vm.prank(msg.sender);
    dscEngine.redeemCollateral(address(collateral), amountCollateral);
}


Similarly, you need to prank the call to dscEngine.burnDsc() using the msg.sender, and you need to call the dsc.approve() function (to approve the DSC tokens of the msg.sender to be burnt on behalf of the dscEngine).
The revised burnDsc() function in the StopOnRevertHandler contract would be:
function burnDsc(uint256 amountDsc) public {
    // Must burn more than 0
    amountDsc = bound(amountDsc, 0, dsc.balanceOf(msg.sender));
    if (amountDsc == 0) {
        return;
    }
    vm.startPrank(msg.sender);
    dsc.approve(address(dscEngine), amountDsc);
    dscEngine.burnDsc(amountDsc);
    vm.stopPrank();
}

You can refer to the conversation on this PR for more details.

thank you so much I can't believe I didn't see this.

You’re welcome, @DylanKatsch. Happy coding!
